# A webapp that uses Spring AMQP is that consired to be 1 client?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

Hi there i am wondering if i create a webapp that uses Spring AMQP. Is that single webapp 1 AMQP client? Or is every request made by a user that results into an AMQP call a client, so potentially x numbers of clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know AMQP much, but I suspect it has the same terminology as [jms](/questions/tagged/jms). In that sense your application is probably pooling connections to AMQP broker for better performance. Each connection in a pool is treated as a separate client (*competing consumer*).

Thus each request is not really creating a new connection (client), but your application isn't a single client as well. In fact, when your application tries to access AMQP broker, it picks any connection from the pool and puts it back once it's done. Another request can reuse the same connection (client) or use a different, idle one.

Comment: I am trying to determine what my strategy would be to use AMQP in a RPC style like way. When a user wants to receive RPC callbacks i guess i need to create a unique callback queu for every request that is done .. Makes sense